# How to fix "Illegal option" error when compiling a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have an application in **dockerfile** where it is necessary to call a **.sh** file to download packages, but there is always an error when calling this file.

My dockerfile is:

```go
FROM alpine:3.12 as builder

ARG VERSION=7.16.0
ARG DISTRO=tomcat
ARG SNAPSHOT=true

ARG JMX_PROMETHEUS_VERSION=0.12.0

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        maven \
        tar \
        wget \
        xmlstarlet

COPY settings.xml download.sh camunda-run.sh camunda-tomcat.sh camunda-wildfly.sh  /tmp/

RUN /tmp/download.sh

FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        openjdk11-jre-headless \
        tzdata \
        tini \
        xmlstarlet \
    && curl -o /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh \
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/a454892f3c2ebbc22bd15e446415b8fcb7c1cfa4/wait-for-it.sh" \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S camunda && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S camunda -G camunda -h /camunda -s /bin/bash -D camunda
WORKDIR /camunda
USER camunda

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./camunda.sh"]

COPY --chown=camunda:camunda --from=builder /camunda .
```

My download.sh file looks exactly like this: https://github.com/camunda/docker-camunda-bpm-platform/blob/next/download.sh

When running the command: `docker build . -t servicecamundadocker/latest` i get the error:

```
 => ERROR [builder 4/4] RUN /tmp/download.sh                                                                                       0.2s ------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN /tmp/download.sh:
#11 0.216 /bin/sh: illegal option -
------
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: the default shell for alpine is `ash` (although `/bin/sh` might be an alias for that) so maybe the `-ex` used in that script is not supported ... Can you try to execute that script in a interactive plain alpine container ?

Comment: can you add the download.sh script contents?

Comment: @Noam Yizraeli done!

Comment: in your script you start with `/bin/sh -ex`, `-e` exits when not in interactive mode (it says in the docs that - `If not interactive, exit immediately if any untested command fails`) can you remove it and try again?

Answer (score 17):

After a lot of research, I found the solution.

The problem is that Windows uses **\r\n** as an end of line, whereas unix only uses **\n**. So, inside my **download.sh** file, there was a **^M** character that led to the error ***/bin/sh: illegal option***

The solution was to copy the code from the downlod.sh file and convert it to **LF**:

- Use the text editor such as **Notepad++** at the Windows machine to convert

  - Go to menu *Edit* -> *EOL Conversion* -> *Unix (LF)*

Once that is done, the docker build works correctly.

Thank you all for the support.

Comment: for those that vi/vim use **:set ff=unix**.

Comment: thank you, good sir!

Comment: or a *.gitattributes* with `*.sh text eol=lf`